testing application context in a spring boot application
When developing a Spring boot application, should I write test cases to test application context and bean configuration ? I am being told that it should be done but I have never done it or seen anyone doing such a thing.

Every spring app I've worked on so far (started writing spring a few years ago) has a contextLoads test. In fact, that test is automatically created when using a spring-boot-starter.  We've modified these tests to call the healthcheck for the app. I think it's a good idea to have, because I've often found bean instantiation issues when this test fails.

have you had a chance to try my answer?

did my answer help?

It is a good idea to have a contextLoads() test, as it can identify issues with bean generation.  In fact, when you generate a new spring project using a spring-boot-starter, it automatically creates a contextLoads test in an [applicationName]ApplicationTests class.   Writing one yourself is very simple:

@SpringBootTest
class AppNameApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}


We've modified our contextLoads tests to call the healthcheck for the application in question:
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        Assertions.assertEquals( 200, RestAssured.get("http://localhost:" + port +"/actuator/health").statusCode());
    }

